# CSV export missing data in column

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am a PS newbie and need to get some more data from a simple one liner.  I am inputting a list of user DisplayNames and getting their SamAccountNames in the output.  It works but I need to now add a 2nd column that outputs the DisplayName so that they SamAccountName and corresponding DisplName (that I inputted) are side by side.  This is because the input is users from 2 domains and I do not care about the remote domain data. The script cannot read the remote domain users anyway and errors out and skips them.  Here is what I have.  I get both columns in the csv but only SamAccountName is populated.

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Scripts\Users.txt" | %{ Get-ADUser -Filter {DisplayName -eq $_} } | Select-Object SamAccountName, DisplayName | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Scripts\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Thank you!

I tried adding DispalyName to Select-Object but the column data is blank.

Comment: add more extra properties to get displayname on you code   this one to add ______   %{ Get-ADUser -Properties DisplayName -Filter {DisplayName -eq $_}  }

Answer (score 2):

`Get-ADUser` only outputs a [subset of AD User attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.aduser?view=activedirectory-management-10.0#properties) by default, to query those attributes not in the default set you need to use the [`-Properties` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-properties).

```bash
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Scripts\Users.txt' |
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Filter 'DisplayName -eq $_' -Properties DisplayName } |
    Select-Object SamAccountName, DisplayName |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Scripts\users.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @j-mo sorry, typo on my side. `-Properties displayName` had to be inside the loop not outside. That edit should fix it

Comment: Thanks, sorry but not totally clear.  Inside the { } ?

Comment: @j-mo yup. but I already updated my answer. So the code in it should be correct now. just copy paste it again